# I need an Authorized Domain for Firebase Authentication for my local Expo/React Native Project

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

**My goal is redirect a user back to my local Expo application after he has verified his email.**

```
firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, 
    {
       url: // need this url to redirect back to my app after the user verifies email
    }
 )
```

***My Expo application is in development, running on an android simulator (localhost).***

I need to make some sort of redirect url/domain for my Expo app that is running locally on my android simulator. I need to be able to type this url/domain into '*Firebase Authorized Domains*' in order to use the redirect url in my code.

Image of '*Firebase Authorized Domains*' below:

[image]

I can generate a local url for my Expo application but it's in the form of "*expo:// <some ip address*>*" and I can't add that to the authorized domains in order to route the user back to my app.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I need a solution for this as well. Not having any luck with my troubleshooting so far.